# Present Pop-up UIAlertController from within UITableViewCell Without UITableView

Tags: swift, uiviewcontroller, popup, uialertcontroller, uitableview

In my iOS app I have a UIViewController ViewController that presents a view that is partly made up of a TableView. The UITableViewCells include a UISegmentControl. When the UISegmentControl's valueHasChanged action is called, I want to present a pop-up. This is the code called within the action:

```
//Check that the text field isn't empty:
    if self.TextField.text == "" {

        self.Status.selectedSegmentIndex = 0
        let viewController = ViewController()
        viewController.alertStatusChangedForEmptyTextField(self)
    }
```

This is the pop-up I have created within the ViewController class that checks if an adjacent text field in the same UITableViewCell is empty or not:

```
//Alert function that handles when toggle is set even though there is no content.
func alertStatusChangedForEmptyTextField(sender: AnyObject) {
    let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Text field has no contents", message: "Please enter a text.", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert);
    alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Cancel, handler: nil));
    showViewController(alert, sender: self);
}
```

I get an error that pops up in the viewDidLoad function of the ViewController, but originates from the showViewController method call within this function (I know because I've tried commenting out only this last line and then everything works fine).

How can I call a pop-up(ViewController) from within a UITableViewCell? Happy to hear suggestions that involve completely different approaches (Creating a custom UITableView subclass? A function that is defined within the TableViewCell class?)

Also, I don't have a root view controller.

Comment: Please post the error

Comment: @SouravSachdeva The error is called on the first method in my viewDidLoad for the ViewController Class (even if I comment out the first one, then the second one will cause the error etc.). The error logged on the console is: "fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value (lldb) " While my source code is highlighted with the error: "Thread 1: EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION(code=EXC_1386_INVOP, subcode=0x0)"

Comment: I think it has to do with  any of your variable's value ,have you initialised the value of  the variable you are storing the text in initially , i think  a better approach would be debug the value of all variables in viewDidLoad() and check which one is nil

Comment: The error does not come up when I load the ViewController initially. Also, when I comment out the showViewController() function, this problem goes away. I can't change the ViewController class because I need it for the tableview that contains the UITableViewCells

Comment: The problem is you are using self as a sender ,self is your view controller , use sender variable from alertStatusChangedEmptyTextField(), i.e type showViewController(alert, sender: sender);

Comment: and better use the sender 's correct type in the function alertStatusChangedEmptyTextField(), rather than AnyObject

Answer (score 0):

check the value of storyboard, there is a good chance that you will find it nil;

```
storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("PopMenuViewController") as! PopMenuViewController
```

I am trying to figure out how to present the pop up from custom tableview cell element. If you figured it out than do share the method :)